# Relational IndexedDB Wrapper

Tags: sql, html, relational-database, indexeddb

I am planning to use IndexedDB to support offline database but having trouble in performing queries and understanding the underlying mechanics of it. Is there a indexeddb wrapper that can enable me to query against indexeddb using SQL queries? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, check out sqlweb - http://jsstore.net/tutorial/sqlweb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my wrapper library https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/ydn-db It will support limited SQL like appengine GQL.

IndexedDB API do not have relational concept nor SQL processor, but relationship is basically relating two object stores by a pair of respective fields. Handling relationship directly is often more efficient than declarative SQL in javascript usage. With declarative SQL language, you tell everything about what you want and wait for the result. OK for backend, not ideal for frontend.

With IndexedDB you don't wait, just open stream of records (cursor) and decide what to do next in each iteration. It is more flexible and **much** faster. Check out `ydn.db.ICursor` for these concept.

Currently, the library is very active stage and not ready thought.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't. But I have a wrapper that is using a LINQ interface to query on the indexeddb: [linq2indexeddb](http://linq2indexeddb.codeplex.com).